# unable to read a row in dataframe using the key

Tags: python, dataframe

thanks in advance for your help.

[image: my dataframe looks as follows]

I can read the row using the following command

```
Energy.iloc['Afghanistan']
```

but `Energy['Afghanistan']` returns a "key error"

Can someone help me understand why this is.

Afghanistan is in the index.

Comment: `iloc[]` takes a row number. `.loc[]` is using index

Comment: Post a working program. We should be able to copy your code, make the fix and demonstrate the result.

Comment: try `Energy.iloc[0]` or `Energy.loc['Afghanistan']` instead

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `loc` instead:

```
Energy.loc['Afghanistan']
```

Comment: Thank you.  I mistyped in my original comment. I meant to say Energy.loc['Afghanistan']

Energy.loc['Afghanistan'] does work.  My question is why does Energy['Afghanistan'] not work, given that 'Country' column is set to index and 'Afghanistan' is listed in that column.  It should be possible to directly reference 'Afghanistan'

Comment: @RSin The reason it doesn't work is because direct labeled indexing to a dataframe would try to fetch the column with that name, so you have to use `loc` for indexing. Please accept if it helps

Comment: Just did. thank you again. New to stackoverflow, that was my first question, so didn't originally get "please accept".